# ADODB RecordCount behaviour changes calling SQL stored procedure with EXEC?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vb6

I'm maintaining a VB6 application that uses SQL Server via ADODB.
I rewrote the lines

```
Sql = "EXEC sp_MyStoredproc " & Format(iParam1) & "," & Format(iParam2)
Call Rs.Open(Sql, Cn, 1, 1)
```

as

```
Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Cmd.CommandText = "sp_MyStoredproc"
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("@iParam1", adInteger, adParamInput, , iParam1)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("@iParam2", adInteger, adParamInput, , iParam2)
Cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn
Rs.Open Cmd, , 1, 1
```

It looked so simple..., but after the change, **Rs.RecordCount** always returns -1.

I have fixed the problem by forcing **Cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient** just before the **Rs.Open** statement, but my question is: *does anyone have an idea why calling a stored procedure via an ADODB.Command of type **adCmdStoredProc** provides a different cursor behaviour than sending an "EXEC..." statement to the server?*

Comment: `RecordCount` gets populated only for client-side cursors. It doesn't matter if you `EXEC` sql or call sp with `adCmdStoredProc` as long as recordset's `CursorLocation` is `adUseClient`. Try setting it just before `rs.Open` (and use enum entries instead of 1 for actual params).

Comment: I know: but EXECing seems to imply a client-side cursor by default, whereas an adCmdStoredProc command seems to imply a server-side cursor by default. That's what puzzles me.